# Routerlink params with directives controlling it

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have the following code:

```
<a *ngIf="!menuItem.children" (mouseenter)="onHoverItem($event, item)" [routerLink]="[menuItem.url, menuItem.code]" [target]="menuItem.target" class="al-sidebar-list-link">
    <i *ngIf="menuItem.icon" class="{{ menuItem.icon }}"></i><span>{{ menuItem.title }}</span>
</a>
```

But some links have the following `url`:

```
http://localhost:3000/URL/undefined
```

Because not all `menuItems` have the `code` set.

So I want to do the following in angular:

If the `menuItem.code` is set:

```
<a *ngIf="!menuItem.children" (mouseenter)="onHoverItem($event, item)" [routerLink]="[menuItem.url, menuItem.code]" [target]="menuItem.target" class="al-sidebar-list-link">
    <i *ngIf="menuItem.icon" class="{{ menuItem.icon }}"></i><span>{{ menuItem.title }}</span>
</a>
```

Else:

```
<a *ngIf="!menuItem.children" (mouseenter)="onHoverItem($event, item)" [routerLink]="[menuItem.url]" [target]="menuItem.target" class="al-sidebar-list-link">
    <i *ngIf="menuItem.icon" class="{{ menuItem.icon }}"></i><span>{{ menuItem.title }}</span>
</a>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You want to pass value?

Comment: @AndreiZhytkevich I want to obtain the behaviour described based on `menuItem.code` existence

Comment: @micronyks I want to set the routerlink based on `menuItem.code `existence

Comment: What if code is set? n what if it is not set???

Comment: If code is set then the routerLink=[url, code] if it is not set: routerLink=[url]

Comment: this indicates you want to pass `code` along when you redirect to `url`. is it what you want?

Comment: Yes, but only when it is defined to avoid things like: `http://localhost:3000/URL/undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a *ngIf="!menuItem.children" 
   (mouseenter)="onHoverItem($event, item)" 

   [routerLink]="[menuItem.url, menuItem.code!=undefined?menuItem.code:'']" //<<<<<<<<<<<<  here

   [target]="menuItem.target" class="al-sidebar-list-link">
   <i *ngIf="menuItem.icon" class="{{ menuItem.icon }}"></i><span>{{ menuItem.title }}</span>
</a>
```